# Customising initials in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, drop-cap

How do I customize initials using bibtex. For instance, several references use 'Gh.' as the initial for the name 'Gheorghe' and I believe they are right. Now, bibtex always gives the initial as 'G.' However, I want to have it as 'Gh.' How do I go about it please?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `Gh.` as initial, it's easy, if not straightforward.

The example uses the `filecontents*` environment just to be self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  title={Le{\c{c}}ons de g{\'e}om{\'e}trie diff{\'e}rentielle},
  author={Vr{\^a}nceanu, {\relax Gh}eorghe},
  year={1947}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A book: \cite{test}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: stupid question.  why the `\relax`?  might not the resulting "initial" sort out of order if there were multiple `Vr{\^a}nceanu`s listed in the bibliography?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's how we tell BibTeX that what follows is just one token. The simple braces aren't sufficient.

Comment: where documented?  not in the (pathetic) bibtex documentation, not in lamport, not in kopka & daly.  what am i missing?

Comment: @barbarabeeton ”Tame the BeaST“, section 13. By the way, I didn't look at it for answering (`texdoc tamethebeast`): it's somewhat folklore.

Comment: super, thanks.  (strange section numbering, doesn't restart with chapters, and isn't shown in bookmarks.)  i think i haven't read this for years and years.  i shall have to do so again.